# hFind return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE

Tags: c++

For my first post in the forum, and because i'm a real beginner, i don't see from where does my error come from. After a selection of multiple files in a folder by the user, i try to rename them, as "image_1.jpg", "image_2.jpg" etc...
I thought my code was good, but i probably did a mistake because it didn't rename, because hFind is always INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE. Can you help me and show me where does that come from? Thank you very much!!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Accueil.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include "calib_cam_relative.h"
#include "calib_las_veh.h"
#include "calib_cam_las.h"
#include "calib_interne.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include<shellapi.h>
#include<conio.h> 


                     string cam;
         if(radioButton1->Checked == true){
             cam="CDB";
         }else if(radioButton2->Checked == true){
             cam="CDH";
         }else if(radioButton3->Checked == true){
             cam="CGB";
         }else if(radioButton3->Checked == true){
             cam="CGH";
         }

         string sfol;
         ifstream fich_chemin("chemin.txt");
         getline(fich_chemin,sfol); 
         fich_chemin.close();

         WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
         string Dossier = sfol+"\\calib_interne\\TOOLBOX_calib\\" + cam + "\\*.jpg";
         cout << Dossier << endl;
         TCHAR* dirname =  (TCHAR*)Dossier.c_str();
         HANDLE hFind;
         hFind = FindFirstFile((LPCWSTR)Dossier.c_str(), &ffd);
         if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
             cout << "erreur" << endl;
         }
         LPTSTR oldfilename;
         TCHAR newfile[260];
         LPTSTR newfilename = &newfile[0];

         int i=1;
         while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd)!=0)
         {
            cout << "le premier fichier est " << ffd.cFileName << endl;
            oldfilename=ffd.cFileName;
            StringCchPrintf(newfilename,8,TEXT("%s\\image_%d.jpg"),dirname, i);
            BOOL rs = MoveFile(oldfilename,newfilename);
            i++;
         }
         FindClose(hFind);
```

Thanks for your answers! Here is the solution!

```
string cam;
             if(radioButton1->Checked == true){
                 cam="CDB";
             }else if(radioButton2->Checked == true){
                 cam="CDH";
             }else if(radioButton3->Checked == true){
                 cam="CGB";
             }else if(radioButton4->Checked == true){
                 cam="CGH";
             }else if(radioButton5->Checked == true){
                 cam="CF";
             }

             string sfol;
             ifstream fich_chemin("chemin.txt");
             getline(fich_chemin,sfol); 
             fich_chemin.close();

             WIN32_FIND_DATAA ffd;
             HANDLE hFind;
             string Dossier = sfol+"\\calib_interne\\TOOLBOX_calib\\" + cam + "\\*.jpg";
             //string Dossier = "D:\\*.jpg";
             TCHAR* dirname =  (TCHAR*)Dossier.c_str();
             hFind = FindFirstFileA((LPCSTR)Dossier.c_str(), &ffd);
             int i=1;
             ostringstream oss;
             oss << i;
             string iss = oss.str();
             string newfilename = sfol + "\\calib_interne\\TOOLBOX_calib\\" + cam + "\\image_" + iss + ".jpg";
             string oldfilename = sfol + "\\calib_interne\\TOOLBOX_calib\\" + cam + "\\" + ffd.cFileName;
             BOOL rs = MoveFileA((LPCSTR)oldfilename.c_str(),(LPCSTR)newfilename.c_str());
             /*if (rs == 0){
                 DWORD dw = GetLastError(); 
                 cout << dw << endl;
             }*/
            while (FindNextFileA(hFind, &ffd)!=0)
            {
                i++;
                ostringstream oss;
                oss << i;
                iss = oss.str();
                newfilename = sfol + "\\calib_interne\\TOOLBOX_calib\\" + cam + "\\image_" + iss + ".jpg";
                oldfilename = sfol + "\\calib_interne\\TOOLBOX_calib\\" + cam + "\\" + ffd.cFileName;
                BOOL rs2 = MoveFileA((LPCSTR)oldfilename.c_str(),(LPCSTR)newfilename.c_str());
                cout << rs2 << endl;
             }
             FindClose(hFind);
```

Comment: You can use [`GetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find out what the problem is.

Comment: But most likely the problem is that you're passing a narrow-character string to a function expecting a wide-character string. You should use `std::wstring` instead.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Yes, that `(LPCWSTR)Dossier.c_str()` is fishy...

Comment: GetLastError send me : "File not found" but when I print the "Dossier", it's the good path. The error seems to come from my (LPCWSTR)Dossier

Comment: That (LPCWSTR) cast only stopped the compiler from telling you were doing it wrong.  It didn't stop you from doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

`string` always consists of `char`. So your code

```
     TCHAR* dirname =  (TCHAR*)Dossier.c_str();
```

is only working if you are compiling with multi byte character set, not when compiling with Unicode character set. Also your next line will not work:

```
     hFind = FindFirstFile((LPCWSTR)Dossier.c_str(), &ffd);
```

`string::c_str` returns you a `const char*`. Technically you can cast this pointer to a `LPCWSTR`, but this will only change the pointer, not the string that it points to. Since the Unicode version of `FindFirstFile` expects that you are providing a Unicode string, this cast makes no sense.

You could either

- compile with multi byte character set or
- compile with Unicode character set and use the ANSI mode functions (adding the trailing 'A' to the Windows API functions) or
- compile with Unicode character set and use `wstring` instead of `string` or
- take a look at how string and wstring are typedef-ed (both are specializations of a template, one with char, the other with wchar_t) and define your own tstring (also specialization of a template, with TCHAR)

Answer (score 1):

If FindFirstFile returns INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, call GetLastError().
The return from that function gives you the error code, which will help you find out why the FindFirstFile failed.
The error code returned will be one of [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: [The fine manual says as much](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: GetLastError send me : "File not found" but when I print the "Dossier", it's the good path.
The error seems to come from my (LPCWSTR)Dossier